# Does anyone have the AllJoyn On to make it available to me?

Tags: alljoyn

I'm need AllJoyn On apk for some applications. Does anybody have one to make it available to me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's now called Dashboard. The source code was released by Qualcomm about a year ago and can be found here: https://git.allseenalliance.org/gerrit/#/admin/projects/contributed_applications/dashboard

You can find just the app on the build server:
https://build.allseenalliance.org/ci/job/dashboard-apk/